# Find and replace special character and special character with character

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to to modify given strings:

```
a = "John;Rich;jrich@gmail.com\r\n" 
b = "John;Rich;jrich@gmail.com\r" 
c = "John,Rich,jrich@gmail.com\n"
```

To one format:

```
"xxx,yyy,zzzz\n"
```

I think the best way to do that is by using regex to find and replace, but I have no experience with it.
I wrote simple code to change `; => ,` :

```
a.gsub(/[;]/,',')
```

I figured out that regex `/(\\r\\n)/` will find for me `\r\n` and `/(\\r)/` - `\r`. 
I have a problem with joining all regexes together to perform whole string modification with one `gsub`.

Comment: Are you sure `/(\\r\\n)/` is correct? My testing at http://codepad.org/ZSO5PJDb seems to indicate that it should be `/(\r\n)/`

Comment: Do you actually have three strings `a`, `b` and `c` or is that one large string containing different line terminators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = subject.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, '\n')
```

RegEx Anatomy:

```
"
[\\r\\n]    # Match a single character present in the list below
             # A carriage return character
             # A line feed character
   +         # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: It seems to be working perfect! Can you tell me one more thing? How can I join it with my `a.gsub(/[;]/,',')` ?

Comment: I know there is possibility to do something like this `a.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, "\n").gsub(/[;]/,',')` but I wonder if there is DRY way to do that

Comment: I am not very well-versed with Ruby, but could assume this if possible `subject.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, '\n').gsub(/;/,',')`...

Comment: This will kill empty lines.  Not a problem if each line arrives in it's own variable though, so probably not an issue for OP.

Comment: @Taemyr: thanks for notifying that one, as i have already mentioned that i am not very well-versed with Ruby at all...

Comment: @Cylian It's a regexp feature not a ruby feature [\r\n]+ will match empty lines in most dialects.

Comment: @Gregy gsub(...).gsub(...) is probably the best way to go, you get limited information on how the match was and you have limited options for passing that on in gsub.  If you absolutely have to do it with a single gsub call it's possible, but you have to match and parse the whole string.  I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a problem with joining all regexes together to perform whole string modification with one `gsub`.

You can pass a hash to `gsub`:

```
replacements = {
  ';'    => ',',
  "\r\n" => "\n",
  "\r"   => "\n"
}

a.gsub(Regexp.union(replacements.keys), replacements)
#=> "John,Rich,jrich@gmail.com\n"

b.gsub(Regexp.union(replacements.keys), replacements)
#=> "John,Rich,jrich@gmail.com\n"

c.gsub(Regexp.union(replacements.keys), replacements)
#=> "John,Rich,jrich@gmail.com\n"
```

You could also use [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove the line terminators and [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-tr) for the substitution:

```
a.chomp.tr(';', ',') << "\n"
#=> "John,Rich,jrich@gmail.com\n"

b.chomp.tr(';', ',') << "\n"
#=> "John,Rich,jrich@gmail.com\n"

c.chomp.tr(';', ',') << "\n"
#=> "John,Rich,jrich@gmail.com\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
a.gsub(/\R/,'\n')
```

`\R`  stands for any line break

Comment: I have tried it in irb with following result: 
`1.9.3-p551 :001 > a = "John;Rich;jrich@gmail.com\r\n"
 => "John;Rich;jrich@gmail.com\r\n" 
1.9.3-p551 :002 > a.gsub(/\R/,'\n') 
 => "John;\\nich;jrich@gmail.com\r\n"`

Comment: @Gregy: I'm not expert in Ruby, may be you have to double escape: `\\R`

Comment: Ruby is not PHP, "\R" matches a literal 'R'.

Comment: @Taemyr: `\R` is not from php, it's a PCRE feature, see: http://www.pcre.org/pcre2.txt

Comment: Sorry.  PHP was the only online tester I found that matches "\R".  The pure PCRE tester did not, not sure why.(Probably because it did not treat the complete input as a single string).  The important point is that "\R" is not in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The pipe character `|` should solve your problem.  `foo|bar` matches either foo or bar, so you can join your regexps as `/(\\r\\n|\\r)/`.

However in your case a better solution is `?`, `(foo)?` matches zero or one occurences of foo.  So you could write your regexp as `/(\\r(\\n)?)/`

To do all in a single gsub you need to do replace the whole string in one go.  You can do this by;

```
puts a.gsub(/([^;]*);([^;]*);(.*?)(\r\n|\r|\n)/,"\\1,\\2,\\3\n")
```

Comment: @Toto should it?  From my understanding you don't need to change `\n` to anything.

Comment: @Toto Actually, I got a problem because it doesn't match.  So when I added the substitue the whole string method I had to extend the regexp.